# get the object which only contains selected values REACT

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, filter

I have an array where I keep Ids of objects. 
I loop through all objects to find the ones containing ids from an array. 
If I select multiple checkboxes I get every object containing any id from the array. But the goal is to get only those objects which contain all of the selected ones.

my code:

```
this.state.filterSelected: ["231", "232", "130"]
data = [
 {
    title: 'title one'
    id: ['130', '231', '232']
 }
 {
    title: 'title two'
    id: ['130', '231', '232', '233']
 }
 {
    title: 'title three'
    id: ['130', '231']
 }
]
const checkbox = () => {
  let base = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < this.state.filterSelected.length; i++) {
    let foo = data.filter(article =>
      article[property]
        ? article[property].includes(this.state.filterSelected[i])
        : null
    );
    base.push(foo);
  }

  let uniqueObj = [...new Map(base.flat().map(o => [o.id, o])).values()];

  this.setState({ print: uniqueObj });
};
```

I only want to get the object with 'title one' and 'title two' which contains all of filterSelected.

last update:

```
if(e.target.getAttribute('vocabulary') === 'tags'){
                property = 'tags_array';
            }
            if(e.target.getAttribute('vocabulary') === 'type'){
                property = 'types_array';
            }
            if(e.target.getAttribute('vocabulary') === 'related'){
                property = 'related_to_array';
            }
```

Comment: Could you post a sample input, and the desired output ?

Comment: you right, I have already edited my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) function inside your `filter` to check if every single element of an array returns a `true` value.

You have to apply it on the `this.state.filterSelected` and then add the `includes` inside of it.

Working example :

```js
const filter = ["231", "232", "130"]
const data = [
    {
        title: 'title one',
        id: ['130', '231', '232']
    },
    {
        title: 'title two',
        id: ['130', '231', '232', '233']
    },
    {
        title: 'title three',
        id: ['130', '231']
    }
]

const res = data.filter(({ id }) => filter.every(i => id.includes(i)))

console.log(res)
```

If your property name is dynamic, you can change the deconstruction in `filter` to :

```
data.filter(({ [property]: id }) => filter.every(i => id.includes(i)))
```

Comment: yeah, that's definitely helpful. I really need it, but there's one thing.
in my case id key is dynamic, thats why i use article[property]

I updated my first post to let you see the property